# Calculate First Date for Product Lifecycle Analysis with pandas

Tags: pandas

I want to use Pandas to do a simple product lifecycle analysis, but I can't figure out how to calculate the first purchase year of each product. For example:

```
import pandas as pd

purchases = pd.DataFrame(  {
'Product Code': ['web200', 'web200', 'web306', 'web492', 'web306', 'web492', 'web492', 'audio700',    
'audio695', 'web200', 'web492', 'audio700', 'audio695'],
'Purchase Date':  ['1/7/2004', '2/2/2003', '5/20/2004', '8/12/2006', '6/17/2005', '5/3/2004', 
'10/12/2006', '8/2/2008', '9/13/2007', '10/1/2005', '4/9/2006', '8/12/2005', '3/12/2004'],
'Product Type':  ['webinar', 'webinar', 'webinar', 'webinar', 'webinar', 'webinar', 'webinar', 
'books on tape', 'books on tape', 'webinar', 'webinar', 'books on tape', 'books on tape']
})
```

I want to create 2 columns:

```
purchases['Product First Purchase Year']
purchases['Product Lifecycle Year']
```

so that for the first row, Product First Purchase Year =  2003, Product Lifecycle Year = 2.

How do I calculate the Product First Purchase Year without using a loop? I'm sure someone else has asked a similar question before, but I'm obviously not using the right search terms because I haven't found it. I'm using pandas v0.13.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably what you are looking for:

```
purchases['Product First Purchase Year'] = purchases['Purchase Date'].apply(lambda s: int(s.split('/')[2]))
purchases['Product Lifecycle Year']  = purchases.groupby('Product Code')['Product First Purchase Year'].transform(lambda s: s.max() - s.min())
```

This gives:

```
   Product Code   Product Type Purchase Date  Product First Purchase Year  Product Lifecycle Year
0        web200        webinar      1/7/2004                         2004                       2
1        web200        webinar      2/2/2003                         2003                       2
2        web306        webinar     5/20/2004                         2004                       1
3        web492        webinar     8/12/2006                         2006                       2
4        web306        webinar     6/17/2005                         2005                       1
5        web492        webinar      5/3/2004                         2004                       2
6        web492        webinar    10/12/2006                         2006                       2
7      audio700  books on tape      8/2/2008                         2008                       3
8      audio695  books on tape     9/13/2007                         2007                       3
9        web200        webinar     10/1/2005                         2005                       2
10       web492        webinar      4/9/2006                         2006                       2
11     audio700  books on tape     8/12/2005                         2005                       3
12     audio695  books on tape     3/12/2004                         2004                       3
```

Notes:

1. Using column names without white spaces makes referencing them
   easier
2. "Python for Data Analysis", Wes McKinney is a great book for starting with Pandas
3. The recipes listed here are useful as well - http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/cookbook.html

Comment: Almost!  Product First Purchase Year is the first year the product was purchased, and Product Lifecycle Year is the Purchase Date year - Product First Purchase Year + 1.  Sorry I wasn't clearer in my question.  But thanks to your code, I now know that transform is the method I need to use.  Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: This was my first Stack Overflow question, so unclear on the etiquette. If your answer is almost there, do I edit it, do you, or doesn't it matter? And how did you get your output table to line up?  When I click "edit" to grab the markdown and copy it to a text editor it's not formatting properly.